# Elastic IP intercepting DNS request

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I have a machine on EC2 which has an elastic IP assigned to it. I ran the following command on it to listen to udp port 53

nc -u -l 53

I then ran from a local machine (not on ec2):

nslookup blah.com *<elastic ip address>*

For some reason this actually resolves the ip address, and nothing appears in the output of netcat. If I run nslookup on the ec2 instance itself and specify localhost as the dns server, then it works as I would expect (you can see the requested domain in the output of netcat).

I have configured a security group to allow external access to the machine via udp port 53.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work the way I expect?

Comment: Just tried changing the port to 54 and it works the way I would expect

Comment: Does it work if you aren't running the nc?

Comment: nc running or not makes no difference, the dns request will always resolve, despite the fact that the machine can't resolve it!

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the elastic IP to help with debugging? Also, what is the output of `sudo nestat -tulpn`?

Comment: relevant line from netstat: `udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53                  0.0.0.0:*                               12059/nc `

Comment: Can't post existing Elastic IP at the moment. Will try to reproduce with my personal AWS account.